# Committing to git has fatal pathspec error

Tags: git

I've updated an existing file `myfile.js`, then ran:

```
git add .
git status #I see my file listed under "Changes to be committed"
git commit -m "Updated xyz"
```

And the output is:

```
/myfile.js 205ms
fatal: pathspec '%' did not match any files
```

I've never seen this before.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `git status`? Is there a file named `%`? Is there a file that contains `%` in the name? What if you add files explicitly rather than using `git add .`?

Comment: Are you trying to delete any file.?

Comment: No I am not deleting any file.  The only file I edited was myfile.js.  No files are named '%' or contain that in the filename.

Comment: It is best to show the output of each command.

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of the problem - a pre-commit git hook.